# Java batch processing

Tags: java, file-io, batch-processing

I will read 2000 files and do some works on them with java. So I think I should use batch processing. But How could I do? My system is Windows 7.

Comment: More specifically, [what have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache Camel / Servicemix ESB in combination with ActiveMQ.

Your first step would be to write the fileNames one by one in ActiveMQ Messages. This could be done in one so called route (a separate Thread automatically by the framework). Here you have several options which component to use. There is a file component which reads files and moves them to done afterwards or you can use a simple Java Bean.

In a second route you read the Active MQ messages (single consumer if it is important to process the files in a sequence or multiple consumers if you want more performance) process the File Content in a processor or Java Bean like you want.

You can stop the Camel context any time you want (during the processing) and restart it afterwards getting the process started at the next file not yet processed by loading / consuming it from the Active MQ message queue.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not provide built in support for batch processing. You need to use something like [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=352

This is a new "Batch" on JSR - javax.batch

Answer (score 0):

You can't read files as a batch.  You have the read one at a time. You can use more than one thread but I would write it single threaded first.

It doesn't matter what OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the ability to work on one file, you have two options: use a file list, or recur through a directory. It gets trickier if you need to roll back changes as a result of something that happens towards the end, though. You'd have to create a list of changes to make and then commit them all at the end of the batch operation.

```
// first option
batchProcess(Collection<File> filesToProcess) {
    for(File file : filesToProcess) processSingle(file);
}

// second option
batchProcess(File file) {
    if(file.isDirectory()) {
        for(File child : file.listFiles()) {
            batchProcess(file);
        }
    } else {
        processSingle(file);
    }
}
```